# Add apple pay on my website, local testing

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I am trying to add Apple Pay on my website

I tried to implement the [Apple Pay JS API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api) but as often the Apple documentation is quite unreadable :D

I made some tests in local, but the Apple Pay button is not showing, not sure because I am not doing it on my verified domain or only available on safari

Before continuing, I would like to be sure I can use Apple Pay on any browser and not only safari, I found everything on internet and for example Stripe is offering it on all browsers, so it should work.